# Autoincrement field dependent for number of specific value appearances in django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm looking for a good example or advice to solve my problem in Django & python. I've simple model like Customer

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    CUSTOMER_CHOICES = [
        ('pc', 'Private Customer'),
        ('bc', 'Business Customer'),
    ]
    customer_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=CUSTOMER_CHOICES)
    customer_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
```

For all customers, I want to build (and show on page) a specific "Customer Number" based on customer type and a decimal number. I think I might store this value in the *Customer* table (somethink like this):

```
|id|customer_name|customer_type|customer_number|
|1 |Private 1    |pc           |1              |
|2 |Private 2    |pc           |2              |
|3 |Business 1   |bc           |1              |
|4 |Private 3    |pc           |3              |
|5 |Business 2   |bc           |2              |
```

Of course, when I'll modify the customer name or other value (except customer type and customer number) I don't want to update this number.

I think the bellow code will not work (this is just an example as first thought), because I don't know how the code will work when I'll have two different sessions and when I press the save button at the same time. I don't know this code properly will handle a new object, when we earlier delete e.g. the second row then next we will want to add "new Private Customer".

edited code:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Get last object by customer type
        last_obj = Customer.objects.all().filter(customer_type=self.customer_type).last()

        # Checking if we had any entries by customer type
        # if not, this element must be first on the list
        # next, if new val is None we need to add 1 to the counter
        print(last_obj.customer_number)
        if last_obj is None:
            self.customer_number = 1
        else:
            if self.customer_number is None:
                self.customer_number = last_obj.customer_number + 1

        super(Customer, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Is Django have any tools to do this really nice?

Comment: What do you mean with "avoid number gaps or duplicate numbers"?

Comment: Maybe avoiding gaps is too wide, but I need to have consistent data.
When I delete Private2, I'll have the gap but it is fine, but when I want to save a new object like Private4 the "customer_number" for this object should have 4.

Avoiding duplicate numbers is when I wand save two objects like Private4 and Provate5, and when I click save at the same time I'm afraid that those objects will get the same customer number because both objects get the same value from a query in variable last_number in the save method.

Answer (score 1):

Django doesn't have a single specific tool to achieve your outcome. Here are two options.

**1. Save() method**
This is basically your approach. But it should be combined with Django's `UniqueConstraint.condition` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint.condition)) method to make sure the customer_number field is unique for each customer type. Model constraints can be set as a [meta option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.constraints).

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    CUSTOMER_CHOICES = [
        ('pc', 'Private Customer'),
        ('bc', 'Business Customer'),
    ]
    customer_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=CUSTOMER_CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstrained(fields=['customer_number'], condition=Q(customer_type='pc'), name='unique_pc_customer'),
            models.UniqueConstrained(fields=['customer_number'], condition=Q(customer_type='bc'), name='unique_bc_customer'),
            ]
```

If the constraint is violated, an `IntegrityError` is raised. You can handle the error in your model `save()` method.

```
def save():
    try:
       #Set your customer_number
    except IntegrityError:
       #Handle the error as you wish
```

**2. Separate models**
You could define two additional models, one for pc one for bc. Those models would then be related to your Customer model one-to-one. The id of your pc model instance and bc model instance would be your customer number.

Comment: Thanks @yagus for your reply! I know that I must everything do in the save method but I'm really afraid of weird cases. I edited the save method, it works, but I don't know that this code will do the job properly.
I do not afraid of integrity, because I will store customer type on the other table.
I know that I can separate models, but other methods might be not clear or I will double the amount of code

Comment: @ashby, it will do the job properly if you add the constraints into your model and handle the integrity errors in your save method as explained in the answer.